# How do I color Riemann integral rectangles using conditionals?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, options, conditional

I'm building a function to visualize the Riemann integration process for any function using rectangles. Everything is fine, except that I need the color of the rectangles to change if they're under the $x$-axis.

In other words, I want the rectangles to be one color when they're "negative" and another when they're positive, keeping in mind that this must work for any function.
Here's what I have so far:

```
LRiemann[f_, {a_, b_, n_}] := Module[
  {dx, i, c, rect, plot, sum},
  dx = N[(b - a)/n];
  c = Table[a + i*dx, {i, 0, n}];
  rect = Table[            
    Rectangle[   {  c[[i]], 0}, {c[[i + 1]], f[c[[i]]]   }   ] ,  {i, 
     1, n}         ];
    plot = 
   Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
    PlotLabel -> 
     Style[f[x] sum "-> Aprox. Area of f(x) = ", FontSize -> 15], 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]];
    sum = dx*Sum[f[a + (j - 1)*dx], {j, 1, n}];
  Show[
    plot,
    Graphics[{RGBColor[166/255, 206/255, 227/255], 
     EdgeForm[Directive[Thin, RGBColor[31/255, 120/255, 180/255]]], 
     Opacity[0.5], rect}]
    ]   
    ]
f[x_] := x*Sin[x];
Animate[
 LRiemann[f, {-3 Pi, 3 Pi, n}] , {n, 1, 60}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False ]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've searched this site for other implementations of Riemann integration? There have already been a number of questions on this.

Comment: Yes, I've searched. To no luck am afraid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a conditional `ColorFunction` within `DiscretePlot` to achieve what I think you want. In that case, it is important to prevent *Mathematica* from scaling of the values passed to the `ColorFunction` using `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`.

The conditional expression used as a `ColorFunction` is given the $(x,y)$ values to be plotted as a `Sequence`. We check whether the second argument (i.e. the ordinate $y$) is negative or positive, and return a color accordingly.

```
Animate[
 Show[
  Plot[x Sin[x], {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}],
  DiscretePlot[
   x Sin[x], {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi, 10/n},
   ExtentSize -> All,
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> (If[#2 >= 0, Blue, Red] &),
   PlotStyle -> EdgeForm[Black], PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
  ],
 {n, 1, 15, 0.5}
]
```

[image: Colored animated Riemann rectangles]

---

If you'd like to obtain different alignments in your Riemann rectangles, that is also simple to obtain when using `DiscretePlot`, by using the `ExtentSize` option ([docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExtentSize.html)). I will exemplify it in the following `Manipulate` construct instead of using `Animate`, which I find awkward with multiple animated variables.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  Plot[x Sin[x], {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}],
  DiscretePlot[
   x Sin[x], {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi, Pi/n},
   ExtentSize -> p,
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> (If[#2 >= 0, Blue, Red] &),
   PlotStyle -> EdgeForm[Black], PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
  ],
 {{p, All, "Alignment"}, {Right -> "Left", All -> "Midpoint", Left -> "Right"}},
 {{n, 4, "Subdivisions"}, 2, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Open"}
]
```

[image: Manipulate with alignment control]

Comment: In case OP might be confused: Marco chose to use the "midpoint" Riemann sum for his demonstration here, but it is not too hard to adapt this for the "left" (OP's) or "right" cases.

Comment: Thank you so much Marco, really helped me out!

Comment: @Diego, I'm glad it helped. I added an alternative method that will allow you to get whichever alignment you would like for the Riemann rectangles.

Comment: I'm confused... you seem to have switched left and right here.

Comment: @J.M. Yep, I had my labels backwards. Thanks for pointing that out!