# Show the number of rectangles under a curve

Tags: graphics, manipulate

I am trying to manipulate the number of rectangles under a given curve, so far I can show the size of each rectangle, but I am not sure how to tell the number of rectangles.

```
RiemannSum[f_] :=
 Manipulate[
  Show[
   Plot[f, {x, 0, 20}, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"],
   DiscretePlot[f, {x, 0, 20, sob}, ExtentSize -> type]
  ],
  {type, {Full -> "Mid-Point", Left, Right}},
  {{sob, 1, "size of blocks"}, 1, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

Can someone give me a hint or suggestion to edit this to show the number of rectangles? Thanks

Comment: There are a number of previous threads on depicting Riemann sums; you might want to search for them here.

Comment: Take a look at [(87481)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87481/27951), [(82688)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82688/27951), and other similar previous questions.

Comment: On second thought, if all you want is simply the number of rectangles, you could use an `Epilog` e.g. in your `Plot` or `DiscretePlot` to add the number to the plot.

Answer (score 1):

```
RiemannSum[f_] := Manipulate[
  Show[
   Plot[f
    , {x, 0, 20}
    , PlotStyle -> Thick
    , PlotLegends -> "Expressions"
    ]
   , DiscretePlot[f
    , {x, 0, 20, sob}
    , ExtentSize -> type
    ]
   , PlotLabel -> Text[Round[20/sob]]
   ]
  , {{type, Full}, {Full -> "Mid-Point", Left, Right}}
  , {{sob, 1, "size of blocks"}, 1, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]

RiemannSum[Sin[x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]