# Troubles With Dynamic,Panel in Riemann Sum Program

Tags: plotting, graphics, dynamic

## Tl:DR: Scroll all the way down

## General overview :

> > 1. This program aims to construct a demonstration of the Riemann sum by
> >        summing up the area of rectangles under the graph of a function.
> > 2. The width of each rectangle is obtained by taking the length of the
> >        subinterval (b - a) and dividing it n number of times.
> > 3. The height of each rectangle is obtained by taking either the
> >        minimum or the maximum of the function in each subinterval.
> > 4. The summation of all these areas is the Riemann sum.
> > 5. The goal is to
> >            display a Panel which has a place for the user to input a
> >            mathematical function a interval and the desired number of
> >            subintervals which results in a graph of the function the Riemann
> >            Sum Rectangles and Numerical Riemann Sum . The Rectangles having
> >            the positive area will be Blue and the rectangles having negative
> >            area will be in Red.

## What I want to create:

> 1. > > The goal is to
>    > >               display a Panel which has a place for the user to input a
>    > >               mathematical function, a interval and the desired number of
>    > >               subintervals which results in a graph of the function, the 
>    > >       Riemann
>    > >               Sum rectangles and numerical Riemann Sum .
> 2. > > The program which will give the user the same options as
>    > >       (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannSum.html), But, I want the
>    > >       *'taking samples at the'*  dropdown to include a Difference Option (the difference between the max and min-height of the function
>    > >       referencing the *myRiemannErrorGaphic* function) rather than
>    > >       Midpoint Option. 
>    > >  It does not necessarily have to be a
>    > >       dropdown but the user needs to be able to choose the option of Max
>    > >       Min,Difference and a button to replot.
> 3. > > Rectangles having the positive area will be Blue and the rectangles 
>    > >       having a negative area will be in Red.

## Restrictions and Requirements:

> 1. > > I can't use the RiemannSum Package as they do in the Mathematica
>    > >           example.See Below.
> 2. > > It is required that I use the 
>    > >  *myInts, myMin/myMax,
>    > >       myLower/myUpperArea, 
>    > >               myLower/myUpperRiemannSum, myRiemannError and   myLower/myUpperRiemannGraphic.*

## Problems I am Having:

> 1. > > My main problem is with the *myLower/myUpper/RiemannError Graphic*
>    > >       functions. Right now, when I run it, it gets hung up very quickly,
>    > >       i.e. Mathematica stops working and gives me the msg 'notebook contents 
>    > >       being evaluated' and then the program stops working.However, if I 
>    > >       delete

```
DynamicModule[{f=x^2,a=0,b=1,n=20},Panel[Column[{InputField[Dynamic[f]
    ],InputField[Dynamic[a]],InputField[Dynamic[b]],InputField[Dynamic[n]]
    ,Dynamic[Plot...

widths)}] ]}]]]
```

> 1. > > the program works fine.  I just have to include [f_,{a_,b_}, n_] 
>    > >            after the function names.
> 2. > > Currently I am Using Panel and Dynamic, I understand I am going to
>    > >       need     some other commands, especially for switching between the
>    > >       min, Max and     Difference functions,the Replot Button as well as
>    > >       general placement    (Display the graph beside the Input Panel, Size
>    > >       of the graph, Adding a     string on top of the Graph Displaying the
>    > >       appropriate Riemann Sum. When Do I need to use Graphics?
> 3. > > I can type in a different fucntion in the Inputfield
>    > >       Dynamic[f],however when I press (shift+enter), it still graphs x^2
>    > >       or whatever I have typed in the code. Or I have to call it By
>    > >       writing something like 
>    > >  myLowerRiemanPlot[Sin[1/x], {.1, 1},
>    > >       10].
> 4. > > I have to intialize all the functions one by one to run the
>    > >       *myLower/myUpperRiemannGraphic* Function. how do I get around this?

## Code

```
  Table[{a + (i - 1) (b - a)/n, a + i (b - a)/n}, {i, 1, n}];

myMin[f_, {a_, b_}] := NMinimize[{f, a <= x <= b}, x][[1]];

myLowerArea[f_, {a_, b_}] := Module[
   {len, min},
   len = b - a;
   min = myMin[f, {a, b}];
   len*min
   ];

myLowerRiemannSum[
  f_, {a_, b_}, n_] :=
 Module[
  {ints, areas},
  ints = myInts[{a, b}, n];
  areas = Map[myLowerArea[f, #] &, ints];
  Plus @@ areas
  ]
myLowerRiemannSum[Sin[x] - Cos[x], {-5, 10}, 5]

myMax[f_, {a_, b_}] := NMaximize[{f, a <= x <= b}, x][[1]];

myUpperArea[f_, {a_, b_}] := Module[
   {len, max},
   len = b - a;
   max = myMax[f, {a, b}];
   len*max
   ];

myUpperRiemannSum[
  f_, {a_, b_}, n_] :=
 Module[
  {ints, areas},
  ints = myInts[{a, b}, n];
  areas = Map[myUpperArea[f, #] &, ints];
  Plus @@ areas
  ]
myUpperRiemannSum[Sin[x] - Cos[x], {-5, 10}, 30]
a = -5; b = 10; f = Sin[x] - Cos[x]; n = 30;
myUpperRiemannGraphic := DynamicModule[
  {f = x^2, a = 0, b = 1, n = 20},
  Panel[Column[{InputField[Dynamic[f]], InputField[Dynamic[a]], 
     InputField[Dynamic[b]], InputField[Dynamic[n]],
     Dynamic[
      Plot[
       f,
       {x, a, b},
       Epilog -> {
         Opacity[0.3], Gray, EdgeForm[Black],
         Table[
          h = myMax[f, {i, i + (b - a)/n}];
          {
           If[h >= 0, Lighter[Blue, .5], Lighter[Red, .5]],
           Rectangle[
            {i, 0},
            {i + (b - a)/n, h}
            ]},
          {i, a, b - (b - a)/n, (b - a)/n}]
         }
            ] 
               ]
                  }]
                         ]
                              ]
myUpperRiemannGraphic[Sin[1/x], {.1, 1}, 5]
myLowerRiemannGraphic := DynamicModule[
  {f = x^2, a = 0, b = 1, n = 20},
  Panel[Column[{InputField[Dynamic[f]], InputField[Dynamic[a]], 
     InputField[Dynamic[b]], InputField[Dynamic[n]],
     Dynamic[
      Plot[
       f,
       {x, a, b},
       Epilog -> {
         Opacity[0.3], Gray, EdgeForm[Black],
         Table[
          h = myMin[f, {i, i + (b - a)/n}];
          {
           If[h >= 0, Lighter[Blue, .5], Lighter[Red, .5]],
           Rectangle[
            {i, 0},
            {i + (b - a)/n, h}
            ]},
          {i, a, b - (b - a)/n, (b - a)/n}]
         }
            ] 
               ]
                   }]
                          ]
                             ]
myLowerRiemannGraphic[Sin[1/x], {.1, 1}, 5]
myRiemannErrorGraphic := DynamicModule[
  {f = x^2, a = 0, b = 1, n = 20},
  Panel[Column[{InputField[Dynamic[f]], InputField[Dynamic[a]], 
     InputField[Dynamic[b]], InputField[Dynamic[n]],
     Dynamic[
      Plot[
       f,
       {x, a, b}, 
       Epilog -> {
         Table[
          h0 = myMin[f, {i, i + (b - a)/n}];
          h1 = myMax[f, {i, i + (b - a)/n}];
          {
           Opacity[.3], Gray, EdgeForm[Red],
           Rectangle[
            {i, h0}, (*lower left vertex, 
            i is the iterator*)
             {i +(b - a)/n, 
             h1}(*upperright vertex*)
            ]},
          {i, a, 
           b - (b - a)/n, (b - a)/
            n}] (*i is the iterater that starts at a, 
         ends one column width before b, 
         and steps in column withs*)
           } 
               ]
                  ]
                     }]
                             ]
                                ]
myRiemannErrorGraphic[Sin[1/x], {.1, 1}, 5]
```

## Reference Material For Mathematica Example#

## This is in reference to ([Troubles With Dynamic,Panel in Riemann Sum Program](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216894/troubles-with-dynamic-panel-in-riemann-sum-program))

Eric W. Weisstein
March 5, 2012

This notebook downloaded from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/Calculus/RiemannSum.nb.

For more information, see Eric's MathWorld entry http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannSum.html.

RiemannSumPlot[f, {x, a, b, n}] plots the rectangles for the Riemann sum of f[x] between x=a and x=b with n subdivisions.  The option SamplingFunction specifies which sampling point determines the height of the rectangle.  Currently implemented choices are maxValue, minValue, LeftValue, RightValue, and MidpointValue. ShowEstimate -> True prints the estimated and actual areas under the curve."

"RiemannSum[f, {x, a, b, n}] returns the estimate given by the Riemann sum of f[x] between x=a and x=b with n subdivisions.  The option SamplingFunction specifies which sampling point determines the height of the rectangle.  Currently implemented choices are maxValue, minValue, LeftValue, RightValue, and MidpointValue."

BeginPackage["RiemannSum`", {"Utilities`FilterOptions`"}]

RiemannBlocks::usage = "RiemannBlocks[...]"

RiemannSumPlot::usage = "RiemannSumPlot[f, {x, a, b, n}] plots the rectangles for the Riemann sum of f[x] between x=a and x=b with n subdivisions.  The option SamplingFunction specifies which sampling point determines the height of the rectangle.  Currently implemented choices are maxValue, minValue, LeftValue, RightValue, and MidpointValue.  ShowEstimate -> True prints the estimated and actual areas under the curve."

RiemannSum::usage = "RiemannSum[f, {x, a, b, n}] returns the estimate given by the Riemann sum of f[x] between x=a and x=b with n subdivisions.  The option SamplingFunction specifies which sampling point determines the height of the rectangle.  Currently implemented choices are maxValue, minValue, LeftValue, RightValue, and MidpointValue."

MinimumValue::usage = ""

MaximumValue::usage = ""

LeftValue::usage = ""

RightValue::usage = ""

MidpointValue::usage = ""

SamplingFunction::usage = ""

RectangleStyle::usage = ""

ShowEstimate::usage = ""

```
Options[RiemannSumPlot] = {ShowEstimate -> True, 
   AxesOrigin -> {Automatic, 0}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All, 
   Sequence @@ Options[Plot]};
Options[RiemannBlocks] = {SamplingFunction -> MidpointValue, 
   RectangleStyle -> GrayLevel[0.5]};
Options[RiemannSum] = {SamplingFunction -> MidpointValue};

Begin["Private`"]

MinimumValue[f_, {x_, a_, b_}] := NMinimize[{f, a <= x <= b}, x][[1]]
MaximumValue[f_, {x_, a_, b_}] := -MinimumValue[-f, {x, a, b}]
LeftValue[f_, {x_, a_, b_}] := N[f /. x -> a]
RightValue[f_, {x_, a_, b_}] := N[f /. x -> b]
MidpointValue[f_, {x_, a_, b_}] := N[f /. x -> (a + b)/2]

BlockCoords[a_, b_, h_] := {{a, 0}, {a, h}, {b, h}, {b, 0}}
RiemannBlocks[f_, {x_, a_, b_, n_}, opts___] := 
 Module[{sample = 
    Evaluate[SamplingFunction /. {opts} /. Options[RiemannBlocks]], 
   rectstyle = 
    Evaluate[RectangleStyle /. {opts} /. Options[RiemannBlocks]]}, 
  Module[{i}, 
   Table[({{rectstyle, Polygon[#1]}, 
        Line[Append[#1, #1[[1]]]]} &)[(BlockCoords[#1, #2, 
         sample[f, {x, #1, #2}]] &)[a + i*((b - a)/n), 
      a + (i + 1)*((b - a)/n)]], {i, 0, n - 1}]]]

IsReal[x_] := 
 Module[{}, 
  If[! NumericQ[x] || Im[x] != 0, 
   Throw["One or more samples are outside the domain."]]; x]

RiemannSum[f_, {x_, a_, b_, n_}, opts___] := 
 Module[{sample = 
    Evaluate[SamplingFunction /. {opts} /. Options[RiemannSum]], 
   i}, (b - 
     a)*(Sum[IsReal[
       sample[f, {x, a + i*((b - a)/n), 
         a + (i + 1)*((b - a)/n)}]], {i, 0, n - 1}]/n)]

RiemannSumPlot[f_, {x_, a_, b_, n_}, opts___] := 
 Module[{graphopts = 
    FilterOptions[Graphics, opts, Options[RiemannSumPlot]], 
   plotopts = FilterOptions[Plot, opts, Options[RiemannSumPlot]], 
   blockopts = 
    FilterOptions[RiemannBlocks, opts, Options[RiemannBlocks]], 
   labelopts = FilterOptions[RiemannSum, opts, Options[RiemannSum]], 
   estimate = ShowEstimate /. {opts} /. Options[RiemannSumPlot], 
   estimatedmessage, actual, actualmessage, functionplot, newbounds}, 
  functionplot = Plot[f, {x, a, b}, Evaluate[plotopts]];
  newbounds = {Min[0, #[[1]]], Max[0, #[[2]]]} &[
    FullOptions[functionplot, PlotRange][[2]]];
  If[estimate, 
   newbounds = {#[[1]] - 0.2 (#[[2]] - #[[1]]), #[[2]]} &[newbounds];
   estimatedmessage = 
    Catch["Estimated Area = " <> 
      ToString[
       TraditionalForm[Chop[RiemannSum[f, {x, a, b, n}, labelopts]]]]];
   actual = 
    Check[Chop[NIntegrate[f, {x, a, b}, AccuracyGoal -> 12]], I];
   actualmessage = 
    If[Im[actual] == 0, 
     "   Actual Area = " <> ToString[TraditionalForm[actual]], 
     "Unable to compute actual area."]];
  Show[Graphics[RiemannBlocks[f, {x, a, b, n}, blockopts]], 
   functionplot, 
   Graphics[
    If[estimate, 
     Text[estimatedmessage <> "\n" <> actualmessage, 
      Scaled[{0.5, 0}], {0, -.9}, Background -> LightYellow], {}]], 
   PlotRange -> newbounds, AxesLabel -> {x, f}, 
   Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}, Evaluate[graphopts]]]

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

## Tl:DR:#

> > - Trying to create a example such as this
> >          (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannSum.html) without using
> >          *RiemannSum* Package.
> > - I am required to use *MyInts, My Min, My Max, and my Area,
> >          myLower/myUpper RiemannSum,myRiemannErrorGraphic and
> >          myLower/myUpperRiemannGraphic*.
> >    Program runs but crashes after
> >          running.
> > - Have to initialize all functions before main function. Inputfield does not work.
> > - Cannot position graph beside InputPanel(of function,Interval and
> >          Subinterval)
> > - Cannot switch between Max, Min and Difference Options.

## Thank you for any and all help

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87481)? Note that the MathWorld stuff was written a very long time ago, and thus had to use a lot of subsidiary functions that would now be built in today.

Comment: Thanks. That code looks like I can convert it to Mathematica and it will solve most of my problems. However, I am still confused as to how to make a Dynamic Inputfield for the function which the program will recognize and output a graph accordingly. I will try and post the new code tomorrow. What is the etiquette here? Do I make a new post with my code or do I just post it in the comments? Sorry, I am a beginner here.